# How does Indeed.com make it to the top of every single search for every single city I search for?

Tags: seo, search-results

I am very curious and want to understand how Indeed.com, the job board and job search engine company, is able to not only make it to the top of search engines for any city related job search but also dominate the top 5 to sometimes 8 positions completely on Google's first page of results when there is more than one city in the US with the same name.

Try it - type in any combination like this: Austin jobs; New York Jobs; etc.. If you type in Boiling Springs jobs, a city name that is found in multiple states, you'll see they completely dominate the entire first page of results starting with position one.

You can also see that same dominance if you type in a company name, like "GE Jobs" or even "PHP Jobs"

How can they do this? First, this is a search engine - there are no real content pages on the site. If you get a list of results and click on one of the links, it takes you to the actual site where the job was found. Secondly, there are more than 40,000 cities in the US alone. I'll admit that there are some extremely talented SEO experts out there, but dominate every "word" plus "job" and "location" plus "job" combination that is typed into Google?

Also, could their URL structure of the the search results have something to do with it? if you get a location result back, for example, its indeed.com/l-Boiling-Springs,-NC-jobs.html. From a developer's perspective, I have never used a construction like that before. As a side note, tripadvisor.com, who dominates almost every query related to travel, uses the same structure. What are these guys doing? Thoughts?

EDIT:
I was continuing my research and I typed in "indeed.com url structure."  Guess what came up in the search results? http://www.indeed.com/salary/q-Changing-Url-Structure-l-Arkansas.html

First, I cannot imagine that there are so many jobs in the world, and so many backlinks to the page, that it merited it's on webpage but also showed up before any other possible result.

How did it take my query, build a page on the fly, and then push itself immediately to the top of google for the result?

Comment: When I type in "New York Jobs", I get newyorkjobs.com first... However I get what you're saying; there are many sites like this but they all differ in ranking depending on who you are and where you are located. So +1 for a good question. I'm quite eager to find this out myself.

Comment: What is the [practical purpose](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) of this question?

Comment: Indeed ranks well and better than most other smaller sites because they have a lot of quality back links. When you typed indeed.com url structure that's quite a relevant result. How many other websites are out there with those words as content and in the URL? site:indeed.com shows me about 100,000,000 yes million results. Can there be that many Resumes and Jobs in the world. Yes. How did Google take your query build a page on the fly so quickly and rank them at the top? LOL That's Google's algorithm and massive diskless arrays working hard for your query.

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting question.

Comment: Quite Simple - paid search.

Comment: For the technical aspect, see the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14545775/1591669

Comment: This is a good question. Why it is off topic ?